# How to reopen a "too broad" question to give the answer

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I know the answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208737/using-networkx-to-calculate-eigenvector-centrality) that was closed as "too broad".  In fact, I was the first person to vote to close it.  More information was added, and it's now ready to go.

Obviously I can wait until other people vote to reopen.  Or (as is likely here), I can post to meta and hope that speeds up other reopen votes.

But given that I was one of the people who voted to close it - it seems that there should be a way I can reopen it quickly (though perhaps this would be subject to abuse?).  Is there any more efficient process?

Comment: This question does not pertain only to one site. The question is about the process, not petitioning the question be reopened.

Comment: @Catija The question is *explicitly* petitioning the question to be reopened.

Comment: @Servy no, it's not... it mentions that as a possibility (I'm assuming they mean child meta)... the question is asking if there's an alternate method considering they were the person who cast the initial VTC.

Comment: @Servy It would be great if the question were reopened, because there is actually an interesting (and surprising) reason that the process fails on the particular case the person encountered.   However, when I realized I couldn't just answer it, the first thing I did was start looking to see if there was a way I could short-circuit the process.  I can't find one.  That surprised me.  (cntd...)

Comment: @Servy ... So my question is about the process - if there is a process for this, I'd like to know it and help others find it.  If there isn't a process, I think it's worth opening a discussion.  I'm the second highest rated person for networkx (next to original developer).  I think I'm a pretty good authority on whether this is a good question (and it is).  I was the first person to vote to close the original question.  It really seems there should be a way for me to quickly reopen it, rather than waiting for a review queue to hopefully clear it.

Comment: @Joel I'm sure you're aware that if you want to request it be reopened, the appropriate place to do that is on MSO?

Comment: @catija - nope.  Wasn't aware of that.  So is posting on the meta (SO in this case) the appropriate approach in general for any question I might be wanting to call attention to?

Comment: Ah. Meta Stack Exchange is not Meta Stack Overflow. MSO deals with issues relating to SO specifcially, MSE deals with issues for the entire network. Questions that relate only to one site (like requests to reopen) belong on the child meta - MSO... The broader question here is fine on MSE, though.

Comment: (edited my response a bit above while you were answering) - I guess the question then is a bit whether it's really appropriate in general to post to meta (SO in this case) to call attention to a single question even if there isn't a broader issue.

Comment: ... I've addressed that in my answer... on most of the sites I use, it's fine... SO may have other thoughts on it because they are just so darn big. You might be better off starting in chat.

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless you are a moderator, the only way to reopen a question is to get the consensus of four other users. Being the first person to close is irrelevant.

If you really want it opened, you can certainly post to the child meta (Meta Stack Overflow, in this case) your explanation to why you think it's not too broad any longer and hope that others agree with you... or you can post it in chat, which may annoy fewer people.

As a note, being able to answer it doesn't make it not "too broad", so you'll need to explain why you thought it was broad and why you now think it's not (the fact that it's been edited to clarify).

It's completely possible that the userbase won't agree with you and the question will stay closed but it's not unheard of to have closed questions reopened.

If you can edit the question to make it less broad (in a way that doesn't change the question too much), this may also help. Our goal should be to save the questions that can be saved, even if it takes a bit of editing to make it fit. An interesting, narrower question that's open is better than a too broad question closed and rotting away. Though, as you say, it's been edited by the OP, so this should be unnecessary.

Be a little patient and it will probably get reopened.

Comment: FYI - my request now posted on MSO is 1 vote from being closed for being off-topic.  I don't have time right now to go to their chat to try to get the question I'd like to answer reopened (I suspect I'll need to put in some effort on the explanation and as I've used up the time I had free already)...  It may be worth adjusting your answer to more clearly recommend chat.

Comment: @Joel **Generally** what I've written is correct... if SO has some specific rules about topicality on MSO that's SO specific. Many sites don't have much activity in the chat rooms, SO does... Telling people to use chat in the case that they're on a site that doesn't really have any chat participation isn't any more helpful.